# NSBundle - (not loaded yet) Error

Tags: ios, nsbundle, localizable.strings

I am trying to get a strings file table for use with NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle.

I am using this method:

```
+(NSBundle*)getBundleForLang:(NSString*)lang{
     //get the path to the bundle
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"localizable" ofType:@"strings" inDirectory:nil forLocalization:lang];
    NSLog(@"bundlePath = %@",bundlePath);

    //load the bundle
    NSBundle *langBundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:[bundlePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
    NSLog(@"langBundle = %@",langBundle);
    return langBundle;
}
```

While it is working great on the simulator, when i try to use it on an iPhone device  i get this NSLog:

```
2011-12-09 00:40:14.533 MyApp[12754:707] langBundle = NSBundle 
</var/mobile/Applications/915E6BCB-EC44-4F1D-891B-EF68E2FA89C2/MyApp.app/he.lproj> 
(not yet loaded)
```

Why isn't it loaded and where is the problem?

Thanks

Shani

Comment: Shouldn't your file be called `Localizable.strings` instead of `localizable.strings`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the case of your file paths.
The simulator (by default) is not case sensitive, whereas the device is.
This could cause the simulator to successfully find the file, but the device to fail.

Comment: Well that was the problem. the interesting thing is that I called the files "localizable" so the case did match. but it is seems that the name is important here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error. Strings bundle, such as en.lproj, does not include executable file. When you try to `[bundle loadAndReturnError:]`, it will fail, and  `loadAndReturnError:`'s [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1411819-loadandreturnerror) will tell you why.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the bundle contains a bundle identifier.
If it does not, despite the path is available, the resources can't load from there.