# can't loaded de.lproj localize string

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I can't localise my project,message is given...

```
NSBundle </Users/iosdepartment4/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6414C70A-78F5-48F6-B9E9-672B2AE482AB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/88BDD237-CB81-4486-977C-6050521AA464/RindaFinda.app/de.lproj> (not yet loaded)
```

I was trying to internationalize my project using a localize.string file in xcode,but file de.lproj is not loading.

My code is

```
NSString* path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"];
NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
NSLog(@">>>>>>>>> %@",languageBundle);
loginlbl.text = LocalizedString(@"Login");
```

Comment: it might help if you describe in more detail what you are doing and when/where you get the posted error message.

Comment: @AV121 try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438859/nsbundle-not-loaded-yet-error

Comment: I was trying to Internationalisation my project using localizw.string file in xcode,but file de.lproj is not loading.code is `NSString* path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"];
    
    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    
    NSLog(@">>>>>>>>> %@",languageBundle);
    loginlbl.text = LocalizedString(@"Login");`

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438859/nsbundle-not-loaded-yet-error) --I checked this thread but mine not working on both simulator and device.

Comment: Ok. Could you answer more exactly on @Volker question? When you get the posted error message?

Comment: Did you got a answer? I am facing same issue.