# lproj file not loaded yet

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have created 3 files with translations:

- localizable.strings (English)
- localizable.strings (Swedish)
- localizable.strings (Finnish)

And I have this method to get string by key:

```
static func localized(key: String) -> String? {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentLanguage, ofType: "lproj") {
            if let bundle = Bundle(path: path) {
                return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle, value: "", comment: "")
            }
        }

        return nil;
    }
```

but I got **"NSBundle < /var/containers/Bundle/Application/213B1469-9751-4459-ABED-80879B80EFBE/Dicken.app/en.lproj> (not yet loaded)"**

Why isn't it loaded and where is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438859/nsbundle-not-loaded-yet-error#comment10429585_8438859 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made extension As this

```
extension String {
func localized(lang:String) -> String {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
    let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)

    return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")

}

let label: UILabel
var language: String?
label.text  = “Hello”.localized(lang:  self.language! )
```

Comment: Your path is wrong delete app in simulator and check your current language
 let langStr = Locale.current.languageCode write above code is your class  and check your current localisation language it will works

Comment: your language is showing wrong. Please select language in iPhone setting which localisation language you want If your language is Swedish than select iPhone language Swedish in iphone setting

Comment: Ok If you want to select language inside in the app than you set your language code as this  
UserDefaults.standard.set("en", forKey: "Apple") // en is English you can select language code 
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

Comment: You are doing wrong code you set en value and your getting ru Please set your localisation language and get this user defaults value and pass this value in your localization

Comment: I added your code: UserDefaults.standard.set("en", forKey: "Apple"); UserDefaults.standard.synchronize(); let langStr = Locale.current.languageCode; langStr is equal "ru"